# How to set Authorization header when refresh window in Next.js + Redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, next.js, redux-saga, prerender

I am trying to set Authorization header with JWT Bearer token.

When refresh window, header is reset.
I set header when "componentDidMount" from localstorage, but much repeated and get undefined localstorage from pre-rendering.

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accesstoken');`

How and where can add global function that set header with value of localstorage? or any other Good solution?

Comment: So the problem is the localStorage gives undefined sometimes?

Comment: Can you show the logic where you're setting `accesstoken` to localStorage?

Comment: when login, backend api returns token and then ```localStorage.setItem('accesstoken ', res.token)```

Comment: @Davo yes, I got sometimes undefined localStorage.
in addition to localStorage , is there any other thing to keep auth token?

Comment: @DmytroMyronenko cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your question that you're using `redux-saga`,so instead of having this logic in `componentDidMount` you can implement auth flow saga that is responsible for setting JWT token in api client and will be invoked during the app bootstrap:

```js
function* authSaga() {
  // This part will be invoked only once during the app startup
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  // Further auth flow logic goes here
  while(true) {
    if (!token) {
      const { payload } = yield take(SIGN_IN_ACTION);
      yield call(axios.post, '/your-sign-in-endpoint', payload);
    }

    yield take(SIGN_OUT_ACTION);
     // etc
  }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(saga1),
    fork(saga2),
    ...
    fork(authSaga),
  ]);
}
```

In addition, I highly recommend you to refer to [this thread](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/14) which contains great authentication flow recipes using redux-saga.

Comment: Thanks, I got error `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`
when refresh page.

Comment: Does this error occur in browser? Or in node.js environment?

Comment: in Browser. i think it is from server side rendering

Comment: Obviously `localStorage` is not available in node environment. You have to use cookies to store access token then.